# Comparing multiple sets for any and any number of X in a list/dictionary using set().intersection()

Tags: python, set, intersection

As in the title, I'd like to compare multiple sets for any and any number of X in a list/dictionary using set().intersection() and output one set with all the matches.

I currently have:

```
asset_list = ["BTC", "ETH", "AAVE", "YFI", "COMP"]
timestamp_dict = {} #this has all timestamps for assets above

timestamp_matches = {}
for i in range(1, len(asset_list)):
    timestamp = set(timestamp_dict[asset_list[0]]).intersection(timestamp_dict[asset_list[i]])
    timestamp_matches[asset_list[i]] = timestamp
```

It returns the dict 'timestamp_matches' with the list of matches for each asset in 'asset_list', which I realise I've told it to. I previously had:

```
timestamp_matches = set(timestamp_dict["BTC"]).intersection(
set(timestamp_dict["ETH"]),
set(timestamp_dict["AAVE"]),
set(timestamp_dict["YFI"]),
set(timestamp_dict["COMP"]))
```

but that means I have to hard code each asset which I can't do for my objective.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of recursive function application can be done with [functools.reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce).

In this example, we use the first set in the list as a base, and then intersect it with each of the other sets.

```py
>>> sets = [{1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4}]
>>> functools.reduce(set.intersection, sets[1:], sets[0])
{1, 2}
```

Your code might look like this:

```py
import functools

asset_list = ["BTC", "ETH", "AAVE", "YFI", "COMP"]
timestamp_dict = {} #this has all timestamps for assets above
sets = [set(v) for k, v in timestamp_dict.items() if k in asset_list]

timestamp_matches = functools.reduce(set.intersection, sets[1:], sets[0])
```

The line

```
sets = [set(v) for k, v in timestamp_dict.items() if k in asset_list]
```

is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) which creates a `set` for each of the values in `timestamp_dict` if the corresponding key is in `asset_list`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want intersection of all sets in your data, you can use a variable to store the first set, and then use it to calculate its intersection with other sets。You almost done it, just need to modify your code a little bit:

```
asset_list = ["BTC", "ETH", "AAVE", "YFI", "COMP"]
timestamp_dict = {} #this has all timestamps for assets above

asset1 =  asset_list[0]
timestamp1 = timestamp_dict[asset1]
timestamp_matches = set(timestamp1)
for i in range(1):
    asset_next = asset_list[i]
    timestamp = timestamp_dict[asset_next]
    timestamp = set(timestamp)
    timestamp_matches = timestamp_matches.intersection(timestamp)
```

By the way, if you do only one thing with one line codes, you will improve your readability of your codes.